# Using the Chebyshev Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is the Q:

A 20 fair coins tosses, (f means the "H" of the coin).
I have to block the probability that I will get n/2+n/100 "H"-s by Chebyshev Inequality. [n=20 in this case...], so:

n/2+n/100 = 20/2+20/100 = 10.2

How I'm doing it?
the result it's much higher then one.

What I get is:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GgV6.jpg)

I'm right?

Comment: I think you $\epsilon=0.2$ is incorrect. How did you get this value?

Comment: Becuse n=20 => n/100=0.2
If I'm wrong, what should I enter?

Comment: The text of the problem is confusing, but if $n=20$, shouldn't it be $10+0.2$?

Comment: and it should be n/2+n/100, so 10 I have at |f-10|, and if I want to get to 10+0.2, I should put 0.2, yes?

Comment: @Alex I edit the Q, I hope it's clear now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if I got the question right, it should be 
$$
P(|S_{20} - 10|>10.2)<\frac{20}{4 \cdot 10.2^2} \approx 0.048
$$

Comment: You got it right, but why 10.2?

it should be 0.2, no?
because we what the amount of "H" will be 10.2 so it's 10+0.2, but 10 we had inside the |...|, no?